# What is the minimum value of $A$?

Tags: real-numbers, maxima-minima

Let x, y be real numbers and let

$A=\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{(y-x)^2+9}+\sqrt{(9-y)^2+49}$.

How do I simply find the minimum value of A? I know the answer is 15 but I need to express the solution in simple steps. I suspect it has no global minima but local.

Comment: what have you tried? what method do you use when you need to find the minimum or maximum of a function?

Comment: then prove that $A\geq 15$ for all real $x,y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Minkowski
$$\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{(y-x)^2+9}+\sqrt{(9-y)^2+49}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x+y-x+9-y)^2+(2+3+7)^2}=15$$
The equality occurs for $$(x,y-x,9-y)||(2,3,7),$$
which gives $(x,y)=\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{15}{4}\right)$.

Id est, the answer is $15$.